# Xcode 10 build 10A255 requires clean build folder for all changes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10

After updating Xcode 10 from AppStore, when i add something even one single line, it doesn't apply change to build while i clean project. Is there any trick to prevent this or is it bug.

edit: i'm developing cocoapod, changes in Example app is applied to compile perfect but changes in development pod is require to clean to apply changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known issue with the new build system of Xcode 10.

There are radars about this and cocoapods developers are aware of the issue.

In the meantime (because it is not gonna be fixed anytime soon), you can indeed switch to the legacy build system (or clean your build folder each time you want to recompile your example app).

Another option might be to disable cocoapods input/output paths, but it is not recommended.

Please note that switching the Compilation Mode build setting from Incremental to Whole Module will in fact not work as intended.

For more information about this you can check the following issues :
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7966
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8073